# JSON syntax error in firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firefox

Im getting a syntax error in FireFox when using `$.parseJSON()`. The same code works properly on Chrome/Chromium, and Safari.

I call this function to get a random generated token to set.

```
function getToken() {
    var url = "/csrf_token_generate";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // Logs the data from the call
        var json = $.parseJSON(data); // Where the error occurs
        token = json.token;
        console.log(token);
    });
}
```

The URL `/csrf_token_genrate` returns a JSON object similar to `{"token":"$2y$10$jcr.P3FNqeji6RqD93LnxeIKs9gYNiPj7cboahz8RCCSgKw7VOfhi"}`

In the URL, I am setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` which works in every other browser.

The error Im getting is this

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
n.parseJSON()                jquery.min.js:4
getToken/<()                 wheel.bak.js:94
n.Callbacks/j()              jquery.min.js:2
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith()     jquery.min.js:2
x()                          jquery.min.js:4
.send/b/<()                  jquery.min.js:4
```

The object that is being `console.log()`'ed is this `Object { token: "$2y$10$60vxSZiVqushBLVHSR5jPO6MquD4…" }`

I just can't seem to track down why it won't work in only FireFox, but works fine in other browsers.

**UPDATE 1**

I figured out that firefox was trying to parse an already parsed object, so I changed the code to be along this

```
function getToken() {
    var url = "/csrf_token_generate";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var json = data;
        token = json.token;
        console.log(token);
    });
}
```

Which now works in firefox, but not Chromium.

So what is there to do than?

Comment: Will the call always return json?  You could try adding dataType: 'json' to the ajax params and let $.ajax do the parsing for you.

Comment: @Taplar The second one. The first is just logging the data it gets from the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check the `Response Headers` -> `Content-Type` to find the actual `Data Type`.
And the compatible code should like this.

```
# for chrome
if(typeof data === 'string') {

}
#for firefox
if(typeof data === 'object') {

}
```

Comment: Wow. I guessed this.