# Jquery ajax requesting not working in FF and safari, working in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

*I have tried all solutions from internet but nothing works so going to ask question.*
I am sending ajax request to PHP script which returns JSON data.
JSON data displaying perfectly in chrome but in firefox and safari its giving parseError.

AJAX request is:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "jjtest.php",
          data: {"sId": sId},
          dataType: "json",

            success:function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                   console.log(errorThrown);
            }

});
```

and PHP script is:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type: application/json');

 $sId = $_REQUEST['sId'];

 include_once("DBConnection.php");

  $stmt= $db->prepare("SELECT tName,time, timeleft FROM new_booking WHERE sId = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $sId);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($teacherName, $timeleft, $time);
  if ($stmt->fetch()){
   $arr = array('teacher' => (string)$teacherName, 'time' => (string)$time, 'timeleft' => (string)$timeleft);
   echo json_encode($arr);


  }
  $stmt->close();



?>
```

**I HAVE TRIED:**

- add content type to php
- add content type to ajax
- add async false to ajax
- add cache true to ajax
- add `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to `json_encode`
- pass all string values to `json_encode`
- remove `dataType` from ajax
- set `dataType` = `text`
- and many more i forgot

  Struglling from 1.5 days.

**UPDATE**:

The error in FF is:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

But in chrome, same works fine.

and returning JSON response is:

```
{
  "teacher": "Lucy",
  "time": "240",
  "timeleft": "240"
}
```

*SO, please help me to sleep comfortably tonight*

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I updated the qstn, please see

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624099/json-syntax-error-in-firefox-only ?

Comment: yes, same. works in chrome but not in FF. if i set dataType of ajax equals to `text` then it displays in FF not in chrome

Comment: @madflow where to add those conditions? in success? ryt? i try

Comment: Adding those conditions wont work with dataType as json, because the syntax error and cratering of javascript is occurring inside the jquery ajax method before it even gets to `success` or `error` callbacks. I really don't know why this is not working in firefox and safari for you... jquery is written to avoid these sorts of situations! Very baffling... I cannot seem to make this fail on mac/pc and firefox, edge, chrome, safari, and opera. SO weird.

Comment: @InredibleHat i agree with you but its happening thats why i asked and i added those conditions and for both chrome and FF its going in object condition.

Comment: maybe error is in returning JSON but it looks good. i can't figure it out

Comment: You could try to add the `dataFilter` function to your settings and throw data into the console. `dataFilter` is executed before the jQuery attempts to parse the json. You could try to sanitize your response data before letting jQuery parse it.

Comment: You could also try removing the content-type header and/or make sure your char set is utf-8.

Comment: Hey @user3154108, I added dataFilter to print data in console and in chrome its printing data right and in FF its printing blank line. what does this mean?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh That could mean any number of things. Try the `complete`function and output it's jqXHR Object to find out more. It also could mean that FF does not accept the mime if your return as is, maybe an about:config setting. It's hard to tell since this means you are not receiving any raw data in the first place. Are you sure your FF has a response in its network tab for your ajax request?

Comment: @user315408 yes, its returning 200 in network tab for both chrome and FF but for FF its response is blank and for chrome response is JSON data. i try to add `complete` now

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Can you also check on your php side whether the request FF sends you does give you a valid ID for your query? Maybe the fault is not in the response but the request.

Comment: @user3154108 YES YES, before coming to thix ajax request there is one another ajax request that stores generated id in DB and in FF that is not storing in DB but is generating so in this request it try to find that id in DB but it is not there. in chrome it works fine. so i have to work on first ajax request first. idk what is happening

Comment: @JagdeepSingh What is your version of jQuery?

Comment: @PerranMitchell its 3.3.1

Comment: @user3154108 you was right. the fault was in request. I have fixed that and now all things works fine. thanks for pointing that out ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the fault was in request ID that was sending to php script. I have corrected that. Ajax was fine.